# mod_rewrite throws 404, however works on (almost) identical server

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I have two VPS's of mine serve the same PHP application, however whitelabled to two different client's brands. The underlaying code is identical. I use a .htaccess to redirect all requests to `index.php`, and then use my MVC to render pages etc. This is my .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>  
  RewriteEngine On
  # Some hosts may require you to use the `RewriteBase` directive.
  # If you need to use the `RewriteBase` directive, it should be the
  # absolute physical path to the directory that contains this htaccess file.
  #
  # RewriteBase /

  Options -indexes
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

It is the same on both servers. My Apache VirtualHost looks as follows:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerAdmin benedict@ovalbit.com
  ServerName  [REDACTED]
  ServerAlias [REDACTED]

  DocumentRoot /var/www/cloud/
  DirectoryIndex index.php

  LogLevel Error
  ErrorLog /var/www/cloud/logs/error.log
  CustomLog /var/www/cloud/logs/other.log Combined

  <Directory /var/www/cloud/>
    Options +ExecCGI    
    AllowOverride all
  </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Running `a2enmod rewrite` returns `Module rewrite already enabled`.

I am almost 100% positive that the file it is redirecting to it available, is there any way to log the result of mod_rewrite requests so I can be sure? Can anyone see any stupid errors I might have made?

I'm certain it's not due to the Apache config as I have another site on the same VPS which also uses a mod_rewrite and works fine.

Comment: For testing comment out `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>` and `</IfModule>` lines to see if you get 500 error

Comment: No 500, just same 404.

Comment: Verify whether your `.htaccess` is enabled or not, by putting same garbage (random) text on top of your `.htaccess` and see if it generates 500 (internal server) error or not?

Comment: No 500 again. I assume this means for some reason Apache is ignoring the .htaccess?

Comment: Yes that's true your .htaccess is not enabled somehow

Comment: Damn I'm an idiot, I've been loading it using the server's IP address, rather than subdomain so it ignored VirtualHost config.